# Circles were one of the parameters is over the Radius of the circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, parametrization

I was working on Complex variable topics, curve parameterization on the complex plane, and I came across [Parametrizing shapes, curves, lines in $\mathbb{C}$ plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986350/parametrizing-shapes-curves-lines-in-mathbbc-plane) since I'm struggling a bit and I'm having some problems.

The thing is if we have the circle described by $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$, and we decide to set $y=10$, the value that $x$ should take is $1 +i\sqrt{99}$, but how should this be interpreted? With a second imaginary axis that takes the value of $\sqrt{99}$? Adding $\sqrt{99}$ to the term of the existing imaginary value (this is, $y$)?

Comment: If $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$, then $y^2 \le 1$, hence $-1 \le y \le 1.$ If $y=10$, then $y^2 =100.$

Comment: @Fred but the solution imposed from setting $y=10$ has a solution, and this solution is a complex solution.

Comment: For $y=10$, the equation $(x-1)^2+100=1$ has no real solution. This equation has solutions in $ \mathbb C:$ These are given by $x=1 \pm i \sqrt{99}.$ But the circle $C$ described by $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ is $C= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1\}.$ Hence $x,y \in \mathbb R.$

Comment: Do you want to **1.** Take the circle in the real plane $\mathbb R^2$ given by that equation and interpret the same geometric object in the complex plane $\mathbb C$ instead? (This would be similar to the linked question, but not allow $x=1+i\sqrt{99}$.) or **2.** Take the circle in the real plane $\mathbb R^2$ given by that equation and extend (via that equation) to an object in the four-real-dimensional space $\mathbb C^2$ by allowing $x$ and $y$ to be arbitrary complex numbers?  (This would allow $x=1+i\sqrt{99}$, but wouldn't be like the linked question at all.)

Comment: @Fred Okay, I get it. Since the circle equation is only defined in the real plane, it won't have any sense to interpret a solution to this in the imaginary plane.

Comment: @MarkS. I think it would be more like the second one. But I think I got it.